# python selenium - locate elements which contains two styles inside style attribute

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Trying to locate all elements on page

```
<i data-visualcompletion="css-img" class="x1b0d499 xep6ejk" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yd/r/A6Wu9TeIieI.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -1304px; background-size: auto; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline-block;"></i>
```

Since attributes inside style such as `background-position: 0px -1304px;` and `;background-image: url(&quot;https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yd/r/A6Wu9TeIieI.png` changes very often i can't locate by style like this

```
style ='background-image: url("https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yd/r/A6Wu9TeIieI.png"); background-position: 0px -1304px; background-size: auto; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline-block;'
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"i[style='{style}']")
```

What I'm looking for is some kind of `contains` including `and`.

I.E

```
 driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(@style, 
'width: 16px; height: 16px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline-block;')]")
```

**AND Style Contains myOtherStyleHere**

This is Facebook Marketplace three dots button

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical `and` operator inside the XPath locator, as following:

```py
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@style, 'width: 16px') and(contains(@style, 'height: 16px')) and(contains(@style, 'background-repeat: no-repeat')) and(contains(@style, 'display: inline-block'))]")
```

The above is example only. The idea is: you can use several `contains` conditions while each of them contains some desired fixed condition.